# From ADC samples to .WAV file in C

Tags: c, microcontroller, wav

I'm making a project about a digital recorder trough microcontroller. I want to store a voice recorded from microphone and build a .WAV file. I have the captured voice samples from ADC, and I only know the structure of WAV file (from this [image](https://www.google.it/search?q=.wav%20structure&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=624&tbm=isch&imgil=5N1fVJlrog6B7M%253A%253BLJoRq8EokZlsgM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.codeproject.com%25252FArticles%25252F29676%25252FCWave-A-Simple-C-Class-to-Manipulate-WAV-Files&source=iu&pf=m&fir=5N1fVJlrog6B7M%253A%252CLJoRq8EokZlsgM%252C_&usg=__BkNLNLWtR3-fE6hHMK8INNk1kuA%3D&ved=0CC0Qyjc&ei=rfe8VIycH4G3UdKkgKAM#imgdii=_&imgrc=5N1fVJlrog6B7M%253A%3BLJoRq8EokZlsgM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.codeproject.com%252FKB%252Faudio-video%252FCWave%252FWAVE_file_structure.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.codeproject.com%252FArticles%252F29676%252FCWave-A-Simple-C-Class-to-Manipulate-WAV-Files%3B551%3B510)), but I don't know anything else of it. Could you help me, giving me some information about the building process of this file type?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that  it makes sence to do it in uC ,I don't think it's even possible. but if you're using Linux you can save the ADC samples in a file and use ALSA to make a wav out of it !

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you think it is impossibile even with a powerfull PIC (e.g. PIC24) ? Or, there is any possibility to do that in C running in a x86-x64 architecture (indipendently from SO)? For my project this is the plane B : store the ADC samples in a txt inside a MMC and then make a custom software, written in C, that convert it in .wav format.

Comment: again I don't think it doable with  uC, and not because of power, you need an OS, so you can handel files, a 'normal' can send and get bits or analog values. you need to make the connection to an OS  work on files like wav or mp3 or what ever , uC is the lowest  level , it just doesn't  fit for the stuff you mentioned.  that been said , if someone has a better idea , I'll be greatful to know it too !

Comment: your custom SW gonna run on  OS ?

Comment: Oh now I understand what your are saying. If the problem is the logical level and not the power of uC, I think I have to explain how my sistem work, because maybe the problem that you mentioned isn't a real problem. I already wrote a part of code when I able to store byte on a FAT16 MMC.I tested it with simple string of character and work well.  I think that if I replace this character with byte wich compoes a .wav file, it will work. But maybe I'm wrong. The custom SW that I have mentioned is the plane B, I not write it yet; i will write it only if the uC solution will not work for any reason

Comment: the stored Bytes in the MMC could be read with ALSA, I'm saying again because its free and pretty simple to use,  but you can't run it directly on the uC, because  you'll need the OS. the header of a wav file is pretty complicated and implementing this in uC is non sense , take a look over here :

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6735

Comment: finally I found the explanation of the various sector inside a WAV file. It isn't so difficult to implement in uC as you said.

Comment: well you can answer you question I'll be greatfull to see how you wanna do it.

Comment: By the way the downvote wasn't from me i upvoted your question since I consider it  interessting

Comment: don't worry I don't consider too much the vote, insteand I thanh you for answer and for suggest another way to solve my problem. Later I will write how I solve the problem, now I'm very busy.

Answer (score 1):

Now I can explain how I making the code. Maybe for someone few part of this explanation may result redundant, but I want to say clearly every pass I did'nt understand.

For first, I wanna explain very single stack of the hader of .wav file, referred in the image I posted upward.

- The first segment , ChunkID, is simply a  char vector "RIFF".
- The second segment, ChunkSize, is the size from this point to the end of file; because the first 2 segment are 8 byte, the value of this segment is simple the total size of file (in byte) - 8 byte. Note that in a variabile-time recording this value is not known at this point, so for first time this is filled by a casual value, and at the end of recording, when the total size of file is known, it will filled with correct value.
- Segment Format is a char vector "WAVE".
- The segment Subchunk1D is char vector "fmt " (put attention at the final space).
- The segment subchunk1size is 16 (decimal value).
- The AudioFormat segment is 2 byte, in my case is 1 for the PCM.
- The NumChannel segment is 2 byte, and its value is 1 for mono and 2 for stereo.
- The SampleRate segment is the sample frequency in Hz (e.g. 44100).
- ByteRate segment is given by ByteRate = SampleRate * BlockAlign.
- BlockAlign segment is given by BlockAlign = NumChannels * BitPerSample / 8.
- BitPerSample segment is the number of bit that compose each sample. In my case of a 10-bit ADC , I have casted this value to 8 bit, losing the less significant 2 bit.
- Subchunk2ID segment is a char vector "data".
- Subchunk2Size segment contains the entire size of the data acquired (sampples), and so it is the entire size of the file - 44, because 44 is the byte count from begin to this point. Another method tho calculate this value is: Subchunk2Size = NumSample * BlockAlign. In any case, this segment is not known at this point, and for its calculation it needs the end of recording.
- The final segment, data, is the vector that contain the sample. Is the only doesn't have a fixed dimension (of course).

Each segment described is in succession, without any gender of delimiter, because the delimiter is intrinsec in the dimension of each segment.
Implement this in C is very simple, if each segment is well described.